# Conditioning on MGF

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, moments, moment-generating-function

Suppose $Z_i$ is the total loss from all losses on policy $i$, where

$q_i=P(there\ are\ losses\ from\ policy\ i),\ i=1, \dots, n.$

Then $X_i$, the total loss on policy $i$ can be defined as $I_iZ_i$, where $I_i$ ~ $Bernoulli(q_i).$

What is the MGF of $X$?

The following is what I’ve tried so far:

$=E[e^{tX}]$

$=E[e^{tIZ}]$

$=\sum E[e^{tiZ}|I=i] P(I=i)$

$=\sum E[e^{tiZ}] q$

How should I approach the next step?

Edit. $Z$ are iid functions, where $X_i=I_i*Z_i$

Comment: What is $Z$?  If $Z$ is intended to be a random variable, what are you assuming about the joint distribution of $(I,Z)$?  What is $\dot q$?  What do the mismatched brackets in "$(I=i]$" represent?

Comment: @whuber Edited the question.

Comment: Thank you.  But what are you summing over?  If it's $i,$ then why does $q$ *always* appear in the sum?

Comment: @whuber I put in the whole question, hopes it help. Thank you.

Comment: @MathAvengers Is $X=\sum_i X_iZ_i$?

Comment: @gunes $X_i=I_i*Z_i$, so $ X=\sum{I_i*Z_i}$ where $I_i$ is a Bernoulli function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* all independence among $I_i,Z_i$:
$$M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]=E[e^{t\sum_i I_iZ_i}]=\prod_i E[e^{tI_iZ_i}]$$

Inside expression can be simplified as
$$E[e^{tI_iZ_i}]=E[e^{tI_iZ_i}|I_i=0]P(I_i=0)+E[e^{tI_iZ_i}|I_i=1]P(I_i=1)=(1-q_i)+q_iE[e^{tZ_i}]$$

$$M_X(t)=\prod_i ((1-q_i)+q_iM_Z(t))$$